# $A_n \subset (X, \tau)$ whit $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ y $\cap \overline{A_n}=\emptyset$ then $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is locally finite

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Lef $(X,\tau)$ a topological space:
Show that if $\{A_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a family of subsets of  $ X $ such that $ A_{n+1} \subset A_n $  $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ , y $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ \overline{A_n} =\emptyset$, then $\{A_n: \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is locally finite.

Seeing that $\{A_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is locally finite, is equivalent to seeing that given a point $x \in X$ there exists a neighborhood $ U $ such that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: U \cap A_n \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite.

For this I remembered the property of Cantor:
Given any countable family of closed $\{F_n \ : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, non-empty and fitted sets ${F_n}$ ($F_ {n + 1} \subset F_n$) then $ \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n \neq \emptyset$, but in the hypothesis it says that this does not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cantor Intersection Theorem is for decreasing nests of **compact** sets, so it doesn’t apply here. We don’t need anything that fancy anyway. Let $x\in X$. Then $x\notin\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}A_n$, so there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\notin\operatorname{cl}A_n$, and therefore $x$ has an open nbhd $V$ such that $V\cap A_n=\varnothing$. Now use the fact that the sets $A_k$ are a decreasing nest to conclude that $\{k\in\Bbb N:V\cap A_k\ne\varnothing\}$ is finite.

Comment: will the following suffice?
as $ A_{N} \subset A_{n0} $, then for all $ n_0 \geq \mathbb{N} $ it will be stated that $ V \cap A_N = \emptyset $, thus we conclude that for all $ n_0 \leq N $ $ V \cap A_n \neq \emptyset $ therefore $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \ : V \cap A_n \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite.

Comment: @Us12: I’m sorry: I missed this comment yesterday. Yes: once you’ve got one $A_n$ that’s disjoint from $V$, then all of the $A_k$ with $k\ge n$ are disjoitn from $V$.